# Exporting Specific Order Details in WooCommerce TXT format

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, export, foxpro

i've been struggling what im going to start to make this function
im looking some plugins that can customize the Export Orders Data, and im using WooCommerce Customer/Order XML Export Suite Extension, And my Company they want to generate it in TXT file not XML file because they need to import the orders data from online woocommerce to local on FoxPro System to update the Stocks in their warehouse inventory.

the format of export should be like this

Example 1

```
Date        Quantity        Customer Name       Cost        Assigned Employee       
07/12/17    5               John Doe            5000        MIRIAM          

No.         Location   Product Name
000001      USA        iPhone S9 Plus
```

Example 2

```
    Varation    Price       Quantity
    PC          110         10
    PC          200         5
    BX          500         3
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is really a Wordpress question.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about WooCommerce, but a little web searching tells me that it can Export its data in either XML or CSV (one version of TXT) format.

See:  [DRAG & DROP WOOCOMMERCE XML & CSV EXPORTS](http://www.wpallimport.com/woocommerce-product-export/http://)

Perhaps the CSV exported data will be enough to meet your needs.

But if not, I don't know if you have the ability to modify your Foxpro/Visual Foxpro application.   If so, you can easily create a utility within your FP/VFP application to either read & import the XML data or to import CSV data.

Once you better understand what options you have, let us know and we can most likely advise you better.

Good Luck

Comment: thank you for your answer, i dont have any choice, im using the csv file instead txt file. :D